# working with forms in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to write form and when submit it write "welcome!" in my page.But after I submit form method still is `GET`!!what's wrong?

this is my models:

```
from django.db import models
import django_tables2 as tables
from django import forms
class Form1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

this is my view:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        # ContactForm was defined in the previous section
        form = Form1(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            return render(request, 'student/Home.html',{'message':'welcome'})

    else:
        form = Form1() # An unbound form
        return render(request, 'student/Home.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my template(Home.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'student:contact' %}"  method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p>{{message}}<p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could be "POST" in the view vs "post" in the form?

Comment: every things is ok. are you sure request after submit is still `GET`?

Comment: thanks for your attention, I figured out what happened. It was just me being stupid again and not noticing that I didn't cloesed quotation marks in form befor method :( thanks alot again.